# Install a python package on an Esri Linux AMI instance

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, amazon-ec2

I have an instance of ArcGIS Server 10.3.1 running under my AWS account that I created using Cloud Builder.  That part went fine and I was able to ssh into the server as the 'arcgis' user without issue.

Now, I'd like to install some extra python packages via 'pip', but 'pip' is not installed on the image.  "No problem", I think, and fire off a

```
sudo apt-get install pip
```

which asks for a password for the 'arcgis' account.  I cannot find any documentation on the Esri Help site, nor via Google that discusses what the default password for this account is, and I did not have to enter it to log into the instance since I used a key file.

How does one go about gaining enough user privileges to install additional software in the Esri Linux AMI images?

**Edit**

I did see [this questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70019/default-arcgis-account-credentials-for-10-2-ami), but that appears to be asking about the ArcGIS Server Manager application account credentials.